# CakePHP Project

Tags: php, cakephp

I've downloaded a CakePHP project, and when I'm trying to login it says incorrect login. Do you know how to fix this problem in CakePHP or else I will have to start coding from the beginning to find out where I'm mistaken while following.  Can you give a hand?

Comment: If you've downloaded some third-party code you don't understand, you only have two alternatives: read the docs (if any) or ask the devs. There's nothing we can do here to help being *powered by CakePHP* the only piece of info.

Comment: I contacted the developer but he is not replying, actually I code this project before but I lost all the data due to my windows corruption, and now I downloaded the project and ran it I'm unable to login and I have to present this project to my fellows. can you help me out If I send you the project files, I'm a beginner and don't know much about CakePHP.

Comment: did you load database?

Answer (score 0):

how about you just comment out the Auth Component in the AppController and you can work on fixing it from there. And read the error messages